# Can I make sudo time out during hibernation?

Tags: sudo, hibernate

I had hibernated my laptop using

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

and then woke it up some hours later to quickly check a document. I re-entered the above command and it worked without requiring a password. I assume this means that the sudo timeout is working from a relative time that is only ticking when the computer is awake, rather than an absolute system time.

I would prefer not to have sudo work without a password when I haven't entered it, in real terms, in the very recent future. Is there a way to enforce the timeout to not carry over like this while the system is in hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

Run the command using the `-k` option:

```
sudo -k pm-hibernate
```

Short version: `-k` means `sudo` will prompt for the password again next time.

From `man sudo`:

> -k [command]
> When used alone, the -k (kill) option to sudo invalidates the user's cached credentials. The next time sudo is run a password will be required. This option does not require a password and was added to allow a user to revoke sudo permissions from a .logout file. Not all security policies support credential caching.
>
> When used in conjunction with a command or an option that may require a password, the -k option will cause sudo to ignore the user's cached credentials. As a result, sudo will prompt for a password (if one is required by the security policy) and will not update the user's cached credentials.